# Properly using natural logs to solve for a variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, systems-of-equations

I'm attempting to take a logistic graph and create an equation using the logistic model of continuous growth. I have taken the equation and simplified it down to

```
a • "e" = 3
```

I know that I need to pull out a natural log, but how do I do that if I am multiplying my e by an unknown variable (a)?

Comment: Do you want to graph the solution of $e\cdot x=3?$

Comment: @mfl no, I'm simply solving for a. I do believe that I should just solve normally and not use natural logs. I was given a graph and iv used data to find points. I will probably delete this question as it's rather pointless

Comment: Ah, with that comment I'm suddenly sympathetic!  Don't delete... I'll answer...

Comment: @fleablood oh I thought what I had done was okay, but I'm always happy to have another perspective!

Comment: My point is ... yes, you are right.  You should just solve it without natural logs.  But as an excercise in using natural logs for the sake of natural logs... it's doable.

Comment: My first comment was somewhat sarcastic as $ae =3 \implies a = 3/e$.  But if you *realize* that and want to know how to solve it with natural logs... well, in math there's always more than one way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you point out in your comment this *is* innane but:

$ae = 3 \iff $

$\ln ae = \ln 3 \iff$

$\ln a + \ln e = \ln a + 1 = \ln 3 \implies \ln a = \ln 3 - 1 = \ln (3/e)$ so

$a = e^{\ln a} = e^{\ln 3/e} = 3/e$.

Inane.  But ... doable.

=====

Of course:

$ae = 3 \iff ae*(1/e) = 3*(1/e) \implies a = 3/e$

is a *lot* more straightforward and is much simpler.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure whether or not to take the natural log of both, but you answered that perfectly. I really appreciate it!